# Thymeleaf - What data type is rowStat.count?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf we can do the following - we all know this:

```
<tr th:fragment="contacts" th:each="contact,rowStat : ${person.contactList}">
<td th:text="${rowStat.count}">count</td>
<td><input type="hidden" th:field="${person.contactList[__${rowStat.index}__].id}">
</tr>
```

**Question:**

What data type is there in "rowStat.count"?

I tried to find different alphabet combination over google to find it but couldnt find anything related to it. Why I am asking this is as it shows as 1,2,3,... on the view and at the same time seems very lucrative phenomenon as it fits my requirement of using it as Integer (if it is Integer, Big "IF") and want to consume it by assigning it to on my entity's Integer field.

Am I thinking in right direction? I mean if it is Integer type, is it a good idea to use it with Spring Data JPA?

Any pointers or information in this regard will be truly helpful.

Comment: No it isn't a good idea to use it as the id of your entity as it isn't unique.

Comment: I dont want to use it as Id. I am looking for incremented Integer numbers.

Comment: Still don't. Find a way that isn't dependend on your view technology.

Comment: But just for curiosity, what data type is there in rowStat.count?

Comment: No idea, just look at the thymeleaf sources and you'll know.